# Replace retrieved languages from gist API with corresponding badges/logos

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, icons, github-api

Here I am creating a react app connected to the github API to retrieve information.

App (Search for a user in index.js): https://codesandbox.io/s/x7n4korjpo

I have a list of programming languages that are retrieved from the public gists (FileTags.js). How do I show the logo or font icons for the languages directly on my web page instead of the text? I've tried using template strings and icons directly in my FileTags.js file but haven't been successful.

I'm trying to convert the below test for example:

Javascript

HTML

CSS

to icons instead so that when the results load, the language logos show instead of text.

Comment: codesandbox link is not working :/

Comment: Check again in index.js and in the preview window, toggle the view. The header, search box and button should appear :) There is a current module view and project view in the window preview

Comment: If I click on individual file I am getting error in most of the files, one such error is Cannot read property 'length' of undefined..

Comment: That's all right as its just a snippet. The functionality of the index.js files works as expected which is the main focus. If you search for a github user like "getify" the function suceeds in retrieving all the languages...but in duplicates as mentioned before